# Unable to call stored procedures using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

```python
connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.callproc('transfer', [1, 2, 1000])# fetch result parameters
results = list(cursor.fetchall())
cursor.close()
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I get this error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\z_data\PYTHON\oops\sql_statements.py", line 66, in 
cursor.callproc('transfer',[1,2,1000])
psycopg2.errors.WrongObjectType: transfer(integer, integer, integer) is a procedure
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM transfer(1,2,1000)
^
HINT:  To call a procedure, use CALL.

[Finished in 0.4s]

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your error. Can you try connection.execute('transfer ?, ?, ?', [1,2,1000]) ?

Comment: No, Its not working

Comment: try `connection.execute('CALL transfer (?, ?, ?)', [1,2,1000])`

Comment: its working ....thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

From

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.callproc

> Note: `callproc()` can only be used with PostgreSQL *functions*, not with the *procedures* introduced in PostgreSQL 11, which require the `CALL` statement to run. Please use a normal `execute()` to run them.

Comment: thanks for the explanation ...its working with execute

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, I was having issues when trying to run a stored procedure.. seems basic now, but ensure you are committing the connection at the end.